# Try/Catch delaying but blocking out the code before it in android development

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I'm attempting to make a basic app and for part of that app I needed a delay after a button is pressed to allow for a text view to show a word for a second, and then change to another word and then have that display for a second and show another word. S0 3 words, 2 delays. i achieve the first delay using postDelayed() which works fine.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bStart:
        display.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        display.setText("READY");
        start.setText("Restart");
        timer.postDelayed(makePattern, 1000);
        break;
    }
}
```

The app displays "READY" for one second then opens a new thread and then starts the makePattern runnable which is where the problem is.

```
makePattern = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        display.setText("GO!");
        for(int x = 0; x < level; x++) {
            pattern[x] = crazy.nextInt(4);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            display.setText("IT WORKED");
        }
    }
};
```

Here it should be displaying "GO!", pausing the thread for a second and then displaying "IT WORKED". However when I run it on both my phone and the emulator it displays "READY" for 2 seconds and then skips to "IT WORKED" either displaying "GO!" for such a short amount of time that it can't be seen of skipping over it all together. I have already tried moving the setText("GO!") inside of the catch and that didn't work either. Any Help would be much appreciated.

THANK YOU!

Comment: That does not come from the try/catch block. You're blocking the UI thread, which leads to blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second `Runnable` and schedule that using `postDelayed`, like you're doing for the first.  In the same place you schedule the first for 1 second later, you could schedule the second to occur 2 seconds later, which would be 1 second after the first.  Or, you could schedule it from within the first runnable for 1-second later.  See the "OPTION" comments in the code below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bStart:
        display.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        display.setText("READY");
        start.setText("Restart");
        timer.postDelayed(makePattern, 1000);
        timer.postDelayed(showItWorked, 2000); // <-- OPTION 1
        break;
    }
}

makePattern = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        display.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        display.setText("GO!");
        for(int x = 0; x < level; x++) {
            pattern[x] = crazy.nextInt(4);
        }

        timer.postDelayed(showItWorked, 1000); // <-- OPTION 2
    }
};

showItWorked = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        display.setText("IT WORKED");
    }
};
```

And just to clarify what's going wrong in your existing code...

As Mael mentioned in his comment, your use of `Thread.sleep` is blocking the UI thread.  Just because the the code is within a Runnable does not necessarily mean that it's running on another thread.  From the Android documentation for [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) (I'm assuming "timer" is a Handler):  "Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached."